# Runtime of function composition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does

```
reverse . sort
```

or

```
sortBy
```

run faster when attempting to sort a list of integers in descending order?

Comment: The performance definitely depends on the order of the input, but I'm not sure how in case of these functions.

Comment: Why don't you try it to find out?  Write a simple case for each using either Criterion or simply using `+RTS -s -RTS` at the command line.

Comment: i'd guess `sortBy` is faster as `sort` is defined in terms of `sortBy` and by using a different compare function might avoid an extra traversal by `reverse`. but i don't see how the comparison would measure the cost of function composition.

Answer (score 8):

I whipped up a Criterion test sorting using `(reverse . sort)`, and `(sortBy (comparing Down))`. Lists to sort were ordered and reverse ordered (should be worst and best cases, not necessarily in that order).

#### Code

```
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main

import Data.List
import Data.Ord

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [ bench "Sort, forward" (whnf (reverse . sort) ([1..10000] :: [Int]))
                   , bench "Sort, backward" (whnf (reverse . sort) ([10000,9999..1] :: [Int]))
                   , bench "sortby, forward" (whnf (sortBy (comparing Down)) ([1..10000] :: [Int]))
                   , bench "sortby, backward" (whnf (sortBy (comparing Down))  ([10000,9999..1] :: [Int]))
                   ]

{-
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 2.290904 us (320001 iterations)
found 79468 outliers among 319999 samples (24.8%)
  734 (0.2%) low severe
  78734 (24.6%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 512.8809 ns (23 iterations)
found 4 outliers among 23 samples (17.4%)
  2 (8.7%) high mild
  2 (8.7%) high severe

benchmarking Sort, forward
mean: 551.4973 us, lb 549.7330 us, ub 553.6538 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 9.998922 us, lb 8.400519 us, ub 12.37726 us, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  4 (4.0%) high mild
variance introduced by outliers: 11.316%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking Sort, backward
mean: 307.6627 us, lb 306.6471 us, ub 308.9350 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 5.790552 us, lb 4.777178 us, ub 7.103792 us, ci 0.950
found 9 outliers among 100 samples (9.0%)
  7 (7.0%) high mild
  2 (2.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 11.365%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking sortby, forward
mean: 168.2486 us, lb 167.7343 us, ub 168.8683 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 2.880548 us, lb 2.448853 us, ub 3.394461 us, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  4 (4.0%) high mild
variance introduced by outliers: 9.467%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers

benchmarking sortby, backward
mean: 262.6001 us, lb 261.3540 us, ub 264.1395 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.096662 us, lb 6.053786 us, ub 8.634885 us, ci 0.950
found 3 outliers among 100 samples (3.0%)
  3 (3.0%) high mild
variance introduced by outliers: 20.965%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
-}
```

#### Summary results

Reversing lists is expensive. The best case test with `reverse` was still significantly (statistically) slower than the worst case with `sortBy`.

Mean runtimes were:

- sort, worst case: **552us**
- sort, best case: **308us**
- sortBy, worst case: **263us**
- sortBy, best case: **168us**

Comment: I don't believe your results are accurate.  You only evaluate to WHNF, which means that most of the output may never be sorted.

Comment: Possibly for the sortBy results. Sort should be accurate. Results evaluating to NF are 347/598us for Sort, and 224/316us. Results vary from WHNF by ~40us for sort, and ~54us for sortBy. The difference is still statistically significant between best case reverse and worst case sortBy.

Comment: Additionally, as far as complexity goes, using `reverse . sort` adds an additional O(n) operation to sort, while sortBy adds (at worst) a constant factor. As it turns out, sort vs. sortBy's comparison algorithms are simply inverse versions of the same algorithm (and therefore have similar performance), and both use the same sorting algorithm, so the O(n) step is the deciding factor in the benchmark.

Comment: Yes, it seems that while the eval strategy does affect overall times, it doesn't seem to change the relative performances.  I do see one odd discrepancy, on two systems (with either `nf` or `whnf`) sortBy's worst case is consistently slightly slower than sort's best case.  Not that it makes `reverse . sort` a better choice.

Comment: @JohnL Not surprising. NF shouldn't be necessary. WHNF is spine-strict, and since you're evaluating the spine of the sorted list (not any of the interim steps) and all of the elements were evaluated for the comparison, NF is just an additional O(n) walk over the list forcing each element (unnecessarily). As for your results, did you compile with `-O2`?

Comment: That makes sense.  Yes I compiled with -O2.  I tried again with the same results.

Comment: Actually it only makes sense for the `reverse . sort` case.  The problem is lists aren't spine-strict, so `whnf sortBy` need not evaluate any more than the head of the list, leaving the tail as an unmerged thunk.  That was my initial objection; in your test I think `sortBy` is doing strictly less work than `reverse . sort`.

Comment: Further research says you are entirely correct. I stand corrected. I still contend that the additional O(n) step is going to make the non-reversed version more efficient, and I have a suspicion that the tests with `nf` are accurate.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your analysis that the non-reversed version is more efficient (and our data from testing with `nf` supports this). The unnecessary element-forcing is at least common to both cases.

Comment: Okay. I was unsure whether the O(n) factor really mattered. But apparently it does in Haskell. I have never really noticed it (even in large) cases with C.

Answer (score 1):

> Does
>
> `reverse . sort`
>
> or
>
> `sortBy`
>
> run faster when attempting to sort a list of integers in descending order?

`sortBy` will be faster. In `reverse` traverses the whole list, so `reverse . sort` will traverse the entire list twice. In fact, the other answer's benchmarks were pretty close to exactly two times as long for `reverse . sort`! If you use `sortBy` you just have to flip the comparison test, so it's to be preferred in all cases.